# Look for all named group occurrences in a string starting with another one

Tags: c#, regex

I have some troubles with building regular expressions in c#.

For example, I have a bunch of strings:

```
1: TestString.WrittenEspecially.ForStackOverflowStringTest
2: TestString.WrittenEspecially.ForStackOverflowString
3: TestString.WrittenEspecially.StringForStackOverflowStringTest
4: TestString.WrittenStringEspecially.ForStackOverflowStringTest
```

I want to find all occurrences of word "String" in lines starting with "1:" or "3:".

I have a regular expression: `^(1:|3:).*(?<str>String)+.*`

But it finds only last occurrences of named group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to use a regex, it is very easy with a variable-width lookbehind supported by .NET regex:

```
(?m)(?<=^[13]:.*?)String
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B13%5D%3A.*%3F%29String&i=1%3A%20TestString.WrittenEspecially.ForStackOverflowStringTest%0D%0A2%3A%20TestString.WrittenEspecially.ForStackOverflowString%0D%0A3%3A%20TestString.WrittenEspecially.StringForStackOverflowStringTest%0D%0A4%3A%20TestString.WrittenStringEspecially.ForStackOverflowStringTest)

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - enables a multiline mode so that `^` could match the start of a *line* rather than a string
- `(?<=^[13]:.*?)` - the positive lookbehind requiring the following pattern immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `[13]:` - `1` or `3` and then `:`
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `String` - a literal char sequence.